# How to render rows of data in React.js from mysql database using Express.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express

Can someone explain or point to some tutorial where is explained how to render rows of data from mySql database into react.js component? 
I've made small database using mysql workbench and this baza.js file inside my project folder:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'db'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM promjer", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

When I run `node baza.js` in my CMD, everything seems fine, I get everything from that specific table inside CMD terminal so I guess my database is ok and it's connected with app.

What troubles me is how to render that data inside my app?
I know that React by itself can't handle data so i should use Express.js. But I don't get what to do with it. Express should be running on other port so how should I even get data to component in app which is running on port 3000 if express is running on port 9000?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you posted contains zero express yet, and it is not connected to anything in any meaningful way. Have express establish the db connection in its main file so you can access it at any time. Next, set up a proper route, like `app.get("/data", ...);`. You'll also need CORS because React is on a different server. Finally, from React, use `fetch("http://localhost:9000/data")...` to load the data from the express server.